# How do I give a line chart a transparent/translucent "area under its line (curve) ?"

Tags: c#, charts

I wanted to give the line plot of my line chart something like a translucent(colored) area under it so that when I have to add another series for comparison, it looks like an overlay of different plot points. I didn't see any relevant information from the Microsoft web documentation, or so I think.

I'm using Windows Forms and the Chart class defined by System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: We need more information, this is too vague. What GUI framework are you using - Windows Forms? WPF? Something else? What chart control are you using? OxyPlot? Something custom?

Comment: Added the information

Comment: An image would help to make the question clearer.. A second series (as proposed) or coding the postpaint event will do the job, but only if the job description is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this code ?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    chart1.Series.Add(new Series { ChartType = SeriesChartType.Area, Color = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Red) });
    chart1.Series.Add(new Series { ChartType = SeriesChartType.Area, Color = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Blue) });
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;

    Random rnd = new Random();

    int y0 = 50;
    int y1 = 50;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        y0 += rnd.Next(20) - 8;
        y1 += rnd.Next(20) - 8;
        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, y0);
        chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(i, y1);
    }
}
```